# Page redirection issue in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to redirect to another page or website in WordPress. I am using below code In which $page variable contains the URL of the website and want to redirect it with a tag href. Problem is the link is appended to localhost current page URL.

the code is here

```
$page= get_post_custom_values('projPage');
if($page[0] != ""){
    var_dump($page);?>
    <p>
        <a href="<?php echo $page[0];?>">Project Page</a>
    </p> <?php
} else { ?>
    <p><em>Project Page Unavailable</em></p><?php
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$page`

Comment: www.google.com is value of $page

Comment: Check my answer @Nikhil Musale, you missed the protocal

Answer (score 1):

Your URL should have a protocol like **HTTP** or **HTTPS** else it is considered as a relative path.

```
$page[0]= 'http://www.google.com';
if($page[0] != ""){
    var_dump($page);?>
    <p>
        <a href="<?php echo $page[0];?>">Project Page</a>
    </p> <?php
} else { ?>
    <p><em>Project Page Unavailable</em></p><?php
}
```

this one is works fine for me